# How to restore removed data from sharedpref after desintall app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I search a solution to reload a data that I saved with shared pref but after that the app was removed and reinstall ( logically the data is remove when the app is delete).  Without use external database, it's possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in iOS. However you can in Android.

All you need to do is open `AndroidManifest.xml` file at `app/src/main`, and check this value is set to `true`.

```
<application ...
        android:allowBackup="true">
...
</application>
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) and [here](https://blog.grapefruitopia.com/post/18755719222/backing-up-and-restoring-a-users)

Comment: You have to do it using `MethodChannel` in Android, and no solution for iOS except saving it in remote database/server.